# Can you help me compute the probability of a match from 2 lists sampled from one big set?

Tags: probability

I got 2 lists: $S_1$ and $S_2$ each contains a number of $2^k$ strings chosen uniformly from $\{0,1\}^n$ (where $2^n>2^k$) (note: $2^n$ is the total number of possible strings).

How likely (What is the probability) is to have at least one *match*? and why? (*match* is a string from $S_1$ that is equal to a string from $S_2$.)

Comment: Minor quibble: $S_1$ and $S_2$ need to be lists, not sets, because if they are chosen uniformly then there could be duplicates.

Comment: The OP may be asking for sets chosen uniformly from all possible size-$2^k$ subsets of the $\{0,1\}^n$. Perhaps s/he should clarify.

Comment: @universalset - I didn't understand what you mean...

Comment: I was asking: are you requiring that your "sets" be actual sets with $2^k$ *distinct* strings, or lists with possible repetitions?

Comment: Though it seems that you've modified your question to be the latter.

Comment: oh, they are lists actually. I edited as you said.